# I want to restrict a particular user from creating a saved class object if the current user id is different from the id in the live class object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**My models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
    # Create your models here.
    
class LiveClass(models.Model):

    standard = models.IntegerField()
    no_of_students_registered = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Class'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.standard) + ' class'
    
class User_details(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, max_length=30)
    standard = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'User_details'

     
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    
class Mentor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    details = models.TextField()
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=2.5)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Mentors'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class LiveClass_details(models.Model):
    standard = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    chapter_details = models.TextField()
    mentor_name = models.ForeignKey(Mentor, max_length=30, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    isDoubtClass = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    doubtsAddressed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LiveClass_details'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.chapter_name
    
    
    
class SavedClass(models.Model):
    class_details = models.ForeignKey(LiveClass_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_attended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Meta: 
        verbose_name_plural = 'SavedClasses'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'SavedClass : ' + str(self.class_details)
```

**my views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate


from . import serializers
from . import models
# Create your views here.

class ListLiveClass(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

class LiveClassView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    LoginRequiredMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

class LiveClassViewId(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    LoginRequiredMixin,
                    generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.LiveClass_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.LiveClass_details_serializer
    lookup_field = 'id'

    def get(self, request, id=None, format=None):
        if id:
           return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, id, format=None):

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.update(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def delete(self, request, id, format=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.destroy(request, id)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


class ListMentors(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.Mentor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.Mentor_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)



class ListUserDetails(mixins.ListModelMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = models.User_details.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.User_details_serializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)



#api endpoints to save  and register live classes 

class SavedClassView(LoginRequiredMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.SavedClass_serializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return models.SavedClass.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)

    
    def get(self, request):
        return self.list(request)

    def post(self, request):
        cur_user = self.get_object()
              #return self.create(request) 
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

**my serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models



class LiveClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass
        fields = '__all__'


class SavedClass_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.SavedClass
        fields = '__all__'

class User_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    saved_class = SavedClass_serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = models.User_details
        fields = '__all__'


class LiveClass_details_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.LiveClass_details
        fields = '__all__'

class Mentor_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Mentor
        fields = '__all__'
```

**In savedClass view in GET request i am rendering all the savedClass Model wherever user in the model matches with the current user , now in POST request i want to create the savedclass row only for the current user and forbids the user from creating a view with different user id**

**I also needs help in my SavedClass model where whether a user is registered or not can only be decided by the admin**

**I tries different possible things but not able to do it, i am new to Django so needs help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the logged in user from `request.user` so something like this should work

```py
def post(self, request):
    cur_user = request.user
    if cur_user.id == request.data.user:
        return self.create(request) 
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

assuming that only logged in users can call this api